# Windows Firewall is blocking Windows Update

Tags: windows-7, firewall, windows-update, windows-firewall

I recently uninstalled ZoneAlarm and have decided to use Windows Firewall as my firewall as ZoneAlarm was causing me grief when I was syncing my iphone.

Anyway, I've noticed just then that Windows Firewall seems to block my Windows updates.

Whenever I have the firewall on, I get a 8024402C error when I try to update, and it seems to update fine when I don't have the firewall on.

there is a help page for this error
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_update/8024402c-error/760ba53f-2cb1-48be-a77f-61bf445fddde

but it seems to assume that the firewall I have is third party, I'm not sure how to fix it if Windows Firewall itself is the firewall that is blocking the automatic updates.

Comment: Actually, I should have noticed the tag...My fault, just missed it.

Comment: nah actually i added in the tag after u noted me on it

Comment: It is important to note, that firewall rules are applied from top to bottom. The first rule has the highest priority. This means if your first rule blocks all outgoing traffic to 0.0.0.0 you won't ever get a connection to the "outside", even if your next Rule explicit allows all outgoing traffic to 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found solution.

I found it [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_updating/windows-firewall-with-outbound-blocking-enabled/d20118f0-64ea-46ea-ad86-1d3ae0706d18).

Essentially I added a new incoming rule which allowed all connections coming from c:\windows\System32\svchost.exe.

I wonder why my default settings didn't already have this? Anyway it worked!

Comment: When adding this rule on Windows 8, Windows Firewall warns me that this rule would not work as expected. Do you know what could it mean?

Comment: Windows Update is calling a remote service. So the rule must be **outbound**, not inbound.

Comment: Allowing svchost.exe will also allow traffic for all the other services on the machine. That might not be what you want.

Answer (score 3):

In Win 8 Go to `Control Panel>Firewall>Advanced Settings`.

Then click `Action>Export policy` to make a copy of your current policy in case you want to restore it.

Then click `Action>New Rule>Custom>Next` in the Program step of `New Outbound Rule Wizard` under the Service heading select `Customize>Apply to this service>Windows Update>OK`

**Optional**: Program: select `this program path` and select the program `c:\windows\System32\svchost.exe` press ok

**Optional**: `Protocol and Ports`: specify `tcp port 443`

`Allow` this connection; select your `profile` or leave as is (it should be explained in the wizard pretty well); give it a `name`.

`Finish`

Comment: It works like a charm, even on Windows 7

Comment: Is it important to specify the svchost.exe program? I'm afraid not specifying it would allow any app to make a remote call. When I specify it, there is a strange message: "Windows Services have been restricted with rules that allow expected behavior only. [...] Rules that specify host processes might not work as expected [...]."

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Control Panel>Firewall>Advanced Settings`. Then click `Action>Export policy` to make a copy of your current policy in case you want to restore it. Then click `Action>Restore Default Policy`.

If it really is just the Firewall, this should allow you to use Windows Update.

[image]

Comment: I have tried to restore to default, however, the same problem still exists. Is this then not a firewall issue? I don't understand how than stopping the firewall will cause it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Open Command Prompt as administrator and type the following commands, one by one (press ENTER after each command):

```
 - netsh winhttp reset proxy 
 - net stop wuauserv 
 - net start wuauserv
```

Try to install the updates again.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/900936

Comment: He already said Windows Update works if he turns off the firewall ("it seems to update fine when I don't have the firewall on"), so no need to reset any of this.

Comment: You're right...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to change firewall settings in Windows 7, you can watch the video to learn the steps ;

**Allow a program to communicate through Windows Firewall**

By default, most programs are blocked by Windows Firewall to help make your computer more secure. To work properly, some programs might require you to allow them to communicate through the firewall.

Watch [this video](http://res2.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/Windows%207/main/d/b/dbb65606-5f4c-42f1-ba9d-ec2bd23b666f/dbb65606-5f4c-42f1-ba9d-ec2bd23b666f.wmv) to learn how to allow a program to communicate through Windows Firewall (1:12)

Open Windows Firewall by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type firewall, and then click Windows Firewall.

[image]

In the left pane, click Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall.

Click Change settings. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

Select the check box next to the program you want to allow, select the network locations you want to allow communication on, and then click OK.

**Warning**
Before allowing a program through the firewall, make sure you understand the risks involved. For more information, see What are the risks of allowing programs through a firewall?

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Allow-a-program-to-communicate-through-Windows-Firewall

Comment: The key is "what program?", or what ports? It is not listed there. It must come under the umbrella of some more esoteric listing.

Comment: @KCotreau : yeah there is no like "Windows Update" program on there for me to choose.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8 and 10, allowing the Windows Update service through the firewall is not enough. It appears to be because it uses a thread pool, but the security context is not correctly set on those threads, so they are not recognised by the firewall as being from Windows Update. [(Link)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e1317d2a-c68a-4a53-88f4-694c1d467188/windows-10-firewall-with-windows-update-service)

The solution that works for me was partially suggested by Uwe Bubeck on the Technet forums [(Link)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/27ded2ad-cc85-4c0a-9b41-c6b469a20aab/windows-firewall-and-windows-update-win-81):

1. Create a link to `svchost.exe`, for example `mysvchost.exe`, by using the command `mklink /H mysvchost.exe svchost.exe`. To do this, you will need permissions on `svchost.exe`.
2. Allow `mysvchost` through the firewall.
3. Change the `ImagePath` for the Windows Update service in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv` from `svchost` to `mysvchost`.
4. Restart Windows Update to apply the change.
   You can now find updates, but they will not download.
5. Add an exception for TCP/80 on `svchost.exe` (i.e. all services). Updates can now be downloaded.

Before allowing all services TCP port 80, I tried adding an exception for TrustedInstaller, moving BITS (background transfer) to `mysvchost`, and some other services suggested by others such as cryptographic services. In the end, I couldn't find which service is responsible for downloading the updates, so I had to add an exception for all services. Downloading updates now works. If someone figures out the minimal set of changes, rather than a large whitelist for all services, please edit this answer (and maybe also post it to the technet threads).

Comment: Somebody mind explaining why this was downvoted? Is it incorrect or does it not answer the question?

Comment: I upvote because I don't know why the downvote. I never understand why someone downvote but don't tell the reason. How to learn if you don't know the reason?